# многопоточное считывание файлов

Tags: c#

Есть обычный тхт. В нем строки эн-тое количество. Как я могу считать их многопоточно, то есть там допустим, первый поток считывает первые 50 строк, второй следующие 50 итд. ?

Answer (score 6):

Нет.

Дело в том, что для текстового файла вы не знаете, с какого именно места начинается та или иная строка: каждая строка может иметь свою длину в байтах. Поэтому для того, чтобы прочитать 100-ую строку, всё равно придётся читать первых 99. Поэтому никакого выигрыша от многопоточного чтения не будет.

---

**Обновление.** Дискуссия в комментариях (идея @avp) и ответ @gbg переубедили меня в том, что технически таки можно разбить чтение текстового файла на несколько потоков примерно равными порциями. Однако существует другая проблема: дисковый ввод-вывод — по существу последовательная операция. Поэтому в любом случае узким местом будет именно он, и несколько потоков будут всё равно бороться за общий ресурс. С этой точки зрения я не вижу большого выигрыша от распараллеливания.

Единственный сценарий, при котором многпоточное чтение может дать выгоду по скорости — это ситуация RAID-массива, в котором каждый поток читает со своего диска. Однако это определение того, какие данные лежат на каком из дисков, вряд ли будет лёгким заданием.

С другой стороны, если узкое место — не чтение, а *обработка* данных, то лучше распараллелить именно её. Для этого удобно использовать, например, PLINQ:

```
File.ReadLines(path).AsParallel().Select(line => Process(line)).ToList();
```

Comment: Хотелось бы еще добавить - что можно читать файл в одном потоке, и сразу передавать из него данные на обработку в несколько потоков. Быстрее вариант врятли найдется.

Comment: @Alexis: Именно так.

Comment: На практике, безусловно, но вообще можно придумать и альтернативный вариант. Например, первый поток считывает первую половину файла, подсчитывает количество строк в ней и отмечает, завершается ли последняя строка в его половине `\n`. Соответственно, второй поток запоминает смещение первого `\n` в своей половине (и может тоже подсчитывать количество строк). Затем они обмениваются данными о наличии `\n` в конце первой половины и смещении первого `\n` во второй. После этого первый поток может прочитать хвост последней строки, а второй скорректировать свои данные. И т.д. и т.п. ...

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42319/discussion-on-answer-by-vladd---).

Answer (score 4):

Общение между потоками не нужно.

Достаточно

- отобразить файл в режиме READ_ONLY на память
- запустить потоки, отдав каждому блок интересного размера.

Каждый поток работает со своей частью по таким правилам:

- Если он дошел до конца своего блока и не встретил конец строки, он продолжает (и залезает в блок соседа), до тех пор, пока конец строки не найдется
- Если поток начал работу не с начала файла, он пропускает все байты от начала своего блока до конца строки.

Никакой синхронизации, никаких блокировок. Понятно, что выигрыш в скорости будет, если файл расположен на дисковом массиве.

**О размере блока**

Предполагаю, что идеальным размером будет - (размер кэша ЖД) * (количество дисков в зеркале массива) / (количество потоков).

Comment: +1, но есть несколько тонких моментов. (1) Нужно заглянуть на символ назад, и если там конец строки, не пропускать начало. (2) Если файл записан в неоднобайтной кодировке, нужно откатиться до границы символа. С кодировками переменного размера дополнительные сложности.

Comment: @VladD это если концы строки - не однобайтные, то есть \r\n. Тогда да, все становится несколько сложнее, принцип остается прежним - синхронизация не нужна.

Comment: Я предполагаю так: первый поток считывает первые 50 строк, если строка равна=="чему-то", то поток останавливается, или не так ?

Comment: @May_be остальные потоки не смогут узнать, с какого байта им начинать обрабатывать файл, вам же уже объяснили.

Comment: @gbg а почему нельзя начать потокам обрабатывать не с байта а именно со строки конкретной и до конкретной?

Comment: @May_be потому, что я (и коллеги) уже раз 5 вам тут написали, что концы строк расположены в файле в виде специальных символов. Перечитайте наши сообщения еще раз.

первая@вторая@третья@четвертая@

Как начать читать со слова "третья", не читая первую половину строки? То есть, как узнать, с какого байта начинается слово "третья" Никак. А файловая система отдает файл только байтами.

Современные программисты ничерта не понимают в железе. Сплошные драные абстракции имени Спольски...

Comment: @May_be - чтобы начать считывать со слова "третья", нужно посчитать все собачки левее слова "третья". А для этого нужно весь файл слева от слова "третья" считать.

Comment: Да, идея, что поток всегда прихватывает один `\n` в чужом блоке, похоже оптимальна.